# vue mixins for changing color of a button for bookmark

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to bookmark some pages in my application. I am adding the pages by their name and url into bookmark. It is working fine. When i click the bookmark button, it is filled with color by showing that it is bookmarked. There are many pages.

I want to use mixins for toggling that bookmark button( if it is bookmarked or not).So, i can use that all other pages. I need suggestions on this mixin part.

**Current code of button and method**

```html
<vu-button
  v-if="bookmark"
  size="reduced"
  color="secondary"
  class="blue"
  @click="addToBookmark"
>
  <svg-icon :name="bookmarker"/>
</vu-button>
```

**method where i am adding that page as a bookmark**

```js
addToBookmark() {
  this.bookmarkSelected = !this.bookmarkSelected;
  if (this.bookmarkSelected) {
    this.bookmarker = 'BookmarkFilled';
    this.addUserFavourites({
      name: this.getFavourites,
      url: this.$route.path
    });
  } else {
    this.bookmarker = 'Bookmark';
  }
}
```

Any suggestion regarding mixin for toggling button will be helpful or how to create mixin for changing color to show added bookmark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to expand your logic here. I'm assuming that you are saving bookmarks through an API, so, I can advise you the following tips:

1. Create an end-point called `pageBookmarked(this.$route.path)` that returns an boolean, in this way you can check if the current page it's bookmarked or not.
2. Create another end-point called `addToBookmarks({ data: extraData, url: this.$route.path })`.
3. Create a last end-point called `removeFromBookmarks(this.$route.path)` to remove current page from bookmarks.

So, now you can create a unique Vue component to manage bookmars:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <vu-button
      v-if="!loading"
      size="reduced"
      color="secondary"
      class="blue"
      :class="{ 'bookmark-active': bookmarked }"
      @click="addToBookmark"
    >
      <svg-icon :name="bookmarked ? 'BookmarkFilled' : 'Bookmark'"/>
    </vu-button>
    <span v-else>Loading</div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true,
      bookmarked: false
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    // Check if page it's already bookmarked
    this.loading = true;
    this.bookmarked = await this.$api.pageBookmarked(this.$route.path);
    this.loading = false;
  },
  methods: {
    async addToBookmark() {
      this.loading = true;
      if (this.bookmarked) {
        this.bookmarked = false;
        await this.$api.removeFromBookmarks(this.$route.path);
      } else {
        this.bookmarked = true;
        await this.$api.addToBookmarks({ data: { name: "My Bookmark" }, url: this.$route.path })
      }
      this.loading = false;
    }
  }
};

</script>
```

I don't think you need to create a mixin for this, just register this component globally and you can access it from every component in your project.

I hope it can helps

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using vuex for add bookmark action or removing bookmark. So how to change that page bookmark part.

Comment: Hi!, I don't think you need Vuex here, but, let me ask you first, are you using an API for your bookmarks operations? Or you are using Vuex actions to call API end-points? please let me know, thanks.

Comment: yes i am using vuex actions to call api end point